# i have a link name ending with date and i need to click on the link ending with latest date in qtp

Tags: vbscript, qtp

I have a link name ending with date and i need to click on the link ending with latest date in the webtable with qtp and the date format is like "2000-10-16"

Sample link names:

```
30000-1-xxxxxxxx 2000-10-16.xls 
30000-1-xxxxxxxx 2008-10-16.xls
30000-1-xxxxxxxx 2014-01-11.xls
```

How can i do this?

Comment: Welcome to SO. What have you tried so far? You'll find people on SO are more willing to help you work through the process and learn if you show some initial effort. Otherwise it can come across as "please do my coding for me", which I'm sure you don't intend.

Answer (score 0):

You have to format the new date and to replace the old date in the source string with the new one:

```
>> s = "30000-1-xxxxxxxx 2000-10-16.xls"
>> d = Date
>> d = Join(Array(Year(d), Right(100 + Month(d), 2), Right(100 + Day(d), 2)), "-")
>> WScript.Echo d
>> set r = New RegExp
>> r.Pattern = "\d{4}-\d{2}-\d{2}"
>> t = r.Replace(s, d)
>> WScript.Echo t
>>
2014-01-23
30000-1-xxxxxxxx 2014-01-23.xls
```